# Ubuntu login screen, ctrl+alt+f1 incorrect password

Tags: login, password

So hi! 
First question, which seems to be a big and common problem. And that is the login screen problem, where everything works fine until you enter your password and hit enter. I've read some posts that tells me to try to open the terminal through ctrl+alt+t or ctrl+alt+f1. Ctrl+alt+f1 is the only one that works, but I cant then login. I type in the name/password of my account, only to get the error message "login incorrect". I have tried several different names but it stills gives me the same error.
It worked earlier today until I tried to extend my partition through gparted.

So my question is

"How can I get into the terminal through ctrl+alt+f1?

Specs: 
Processor: Eight core amd
Ram: 8gb gddr5
Graphic card: sapphire radeon r9 290
Dualboot. Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works, try entering your username login in ALL LOWERCASE. I pulled my hair out before finally coming to this solution!

Comment: You are my hero :)

Answer (score 0):

Your specs have nothing to do with this ;-)
How to login:
Exactly as you did:
Type username [enter]
Type password [enter]

Either you miss-typed (capslock) or the shadow-file / passwd file os corrupt.

You can boot using the Live Ubuntu, chroot into the existing install and set a new password.